# Windows Phone 8.1 or 10 to Get Unanswered Calls From C# Application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have a lil complecated infstructure.I am trying to get unanswered calls from microsoft 535 phone. And i want connect my phone with usb and get this info. does anyone help me how to get unanswered call logs? Because i found to get phonebook numbers but i couldnt get unanswered call logs. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with the current SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible in windows phone 8.1 and also in windows phone 10